# Access a locked folder

Tags: windows-xp, locked, protected-folders

Ok so my supervisor is currently testing something with Windows Permission Settings for folders, basically setting who can access it and who can't. He wants me to find out if I can get in, without permissions.

Basically checking how secure this method is to protect a folder from unwanted access.

So my question is, Is it possible to get into the folder without third party software?

Please note: I am **NOT** asking how to do this, just want to know if it is possible.

Comment: In my opinion, you would have much better luck asking this on superuser.

Comment: i didn't know where to ask it lol, normally this place solves my programming probs so thought they might be able to help here to. Link for superuser please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all file access is performed through Windows, Windows permissions will be respected for any attempt to access a file.

To access the file without using Windows, you could boot on a Linux CD, but I suppose that would qualify as "third party software" in your question.

If a user has sufficient permission on the parent folder, the user may be able to modify the permissions on the folder you're trying to protect.  This would generally only be available to someone with an admin account.

Aside from the above caveats, the Windows Permissions settings are perfectly secure.

Comment: Sorry, Jeremy, but this is not exactly so. With kernel-mode driver you can bypass such security measures. Another question is that installation of the kernel-mode driver itself requires administrative rights, however there exist tricks for bypassing this too.

Comment: My guess is that this would count as "third party software" from moonblade's perspective, but that's good to know.  It's best to rely on encryption if you want to be sure.